# No Prompt in Firefox Browser Console?

Tags: firefox, console, firefox-addon, privileges

I'm using Firefox for Ubuntu, version 39.0. I'm trying to debug an add-on and would like to run some JavaScript under chrome privileges. According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) I should be able to do this in the Browser Console.

If I click on Tools -> Web Developer -> Browser Console in the Firefox menu, I get the Browser Console:

[image]

Only problem is, I can't evaluate anything. My question is: where's the prompt? Apparently this window [should have a prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console). Things I have tried:

- Restarting Firefox with add-ons disabled (safe mode)
- Starting Firefox as a sudo user

Any tips?

Comment: You have to enable developer preferences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Comment: Legend, I set devtools.chrome.enabled to true and that was it. Submit an answer if you like and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Awesome Sammy thanks for that specific preference share, I didn't know it was exactly that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable developer preferences:

"Setting up an extension development environment" MDN page from

- [archived by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191003194337/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences)
- [archived by Unified XUL Platform MDN Backup](http://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences)

Thanks to your research it looks like it was the `devtools.chrome.enabled` preference.

Answer (score 0):

Hello To show firefox browser console log when the console is not showing in console log window please follow the below procedures

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html

```
NB: The Browser Console command line (to execute JavaScript expressions) is disabled by default. To enable it set the devtools.chrome.enabled preference to true in about:config, or set the “Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes” (Firefox 40 and later) option in the developer tool settings.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).